# Replace UITableViewCell AccessoryView by a simple UILabel - Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios

---

I am using Xamarin.iOS and I have just subclassed my UITableViewCell in order to put this code inside the LayoutSubviews() method:

```
UILabel label = new UILabel();
label.Text = "Some text here";
UIView view = new UIView (new CGRect(x,y,height,width));
view.addSubview(label);
AccessoryView = view;
```

As you can see, I wanna simply create a UIView, holding my text label, so that the accessory view on the right side of the table view (usually a checkmark or an arrow) is replaced by my text label. 
Unfortunately the app crashes when I run this code, but the debugger doesn't even realise that the app isn't responding anymore (which is usually never happening). 
I have to ideas:

1. The coordinates & height,width of the rectangle for the UIView aren't ok like that ... But I tried a few and nothing worked, big, small, whichever.
2. It's because I am doing it inside the LayoutSubviews() method ... But usually this is the best place to do such visual changes, without interfering with the storyboard or anything else.

Do you have any idea why my method is not working, or do you maybe even have a better way?

***Any help desperately appreciated,
Cheers!***

Comment: None related tip, `UILabel` is a `UIView` already.

Comment: I don't have experience with xamarin, but if you would use XCode as IDE you can set an exception breakpoint